# How to check if a string contains at least one letter different from 4 using bash or awk

Tags: awk

How to check that a sequence has at least one letter that is not A, U, C, G characters using awk or bash?

Can it be done without the typical for loop?

Example of sequence:
AUVGAU

I give this as input I should get it back given that it has V

The input file looks something like this, so I think awk would be better.

```
>7A0E_1|
AUVGAU
>7A0E_2|
GUCAU
```

Expected output

```
>7A0E_1|
AUVGAU
```

Here is what I tried:

```
awk '!/^>/ {next}; {getline s}; s !~ /AUGC/ { print $0 "\n" s }' sample
```

But obviously /AUGC/ is not right... can someone help me with this regex?

Comment: `grep '[^AUGC]' <<< 'AUVGAU'`

Comment: Alternatively, something like a fasta validator? E.g. https://github.com/linsalrob/fasta_validator

Comment: thanks! I am trying to filter out RNA from PDB protein fasta files :)

Comment: @Jetchisel, I think I need awk to keep the lines starting with ">", do you know a workaround for this?

Comment: I want to keep the > lines if the following line contains at least one char that is NOT AUGC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think `awk` is the tool if you want to conditionally output the `>` line if the next record does not contain `[AUCG]`. You can do that with:

```
awk '/^>/ {rec=$0; next} /[^AUGC]/ {printf "%s\n%s\n", rec, $0}' sample
```

In your case that results in:

```
$ awk '/^>/ {rec=$0; next} /[^AUGC]/ {printf "%s\n%s\n", rec, $0}' sample
>7A0E_1|
AUVGAU
```

(**note:** you can use `print rec; print` instead of `printf`, but `printf` above reduced the output to a single call)

Where you ran into trouble was forgetting to save the current record that began with `>` and then using `getline` -- which wasn't needed at all.

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense. What does [^AUGC] mean exactly? I would have thought only sequences not STARTING with any of those 4 letters.

Comment: It is a `[ ... ]` character class that will match any character within it -- to negate the match you include the circumflex `'^'` as the first character. (you can also use `'!'` as the first character to negate the match, but using the circumflex is more widely used) So `[^AUGC]` says match the line if it does NOT include any of those characters `:)`

Comment: I think the `[ ... ]` is called a *bracket expression* since character classes are already inside a bracket and colon. Which is stated/described by `man 7 regex`

Comment: Yes, it goes by several different names depending on the context. In shell it is a character class (and POSIX pre-defines a number of them `[:blank:]`, `[:digit:]`, etc..), as part of a REGEX, I'm not positive what the "official" name is -- but I suspect you are correct with the bracket expression. For a REGEX, your reference is the correct source.

Comment: In POSIX terminology `[...]` is a bracket expression while `[:blank:]` is a character class and `[[:blank:]]` is a bracket expression containing a character class. There is non-POSIX terminology that refers to `[...]` as a character class and `[:blank:]` as a "POSIX character class" and has other hard to understand definitions where in some contexts `[...]` can alternatively be named a "POSIX bracket expression" (see https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) but that's all very messy and confusing at best so it's much simpler and clearer to just use the POSIX terminology.

Comment: Regarding `printf "%s\n%s\n", rec, $0` - consider using `print rec ORS $0` instead. It's not only more concise but more robust and portable and makes it easier to modify the script in future as it uses whatever value `ORS` has instead of hard-coding the value you hope `ORS` will have (`\n`).

Comment: Thank you @EdMorton, that would eliminate the conversion processing by `printf()` (I actually knew that, but fell back on the first thing that came to mind `:)`

Answer (score 0):

*How to check that a sequence has at least one letter that is not A, U, C, G characters using awk(...)? Can it be done without the typical for loop?*

Yes, GNU `AWK` can do that. Let `file.txt` content be

```
AUVGAU

AUCG
```

(empty line is intentional) then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[^AUCG]"}{print NF>=1}' file.txt
```

output

```
1
0
0
```

Explanation: both solutions count number of characters which are not one of: *A, U, C, G*, any other character is treated as constituing field and number of fields (`NF`) is then checked (`>=1`). Note that this solution does redefine what is field and if that is problem you might use [patsplit](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) instead

```
awk '{patsplit($0,arr,"[^AUCG]");print length(arr)>=1}' file.txt
```

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*